# JAR files required BY the JRE

Tags: java, jar, jdk1.8-73

I came across a particularly odd exam question. The question is:

**"List the 4 JAR files needed by the JRE".**

I find this weird because when I look in my jdk/jre folder, there is a whole lot more than 4 jar files. So my question is, is the above mentioned question invalid? Or am I not understanding exactly what the question is asking? And if so, what are the 4 required jar files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this answers the question. The question can be basic or can be a lot deeper.

But AFAIK, some important Jar's are -

1. rt.jar
2. localedata.jar
3. tools.jar
4. dt.jar**

Reason being, they are an important part of JDK and JRE hirarchy.
You can google about them if required.

Comment: thanks, for a sec i thought it was a trivial question

Comment: Do you know why localedata.jar would be a required JAR file? It's marked as optional in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jre-8-readme-2095710.html